# Upload a large file (1GB) with node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to upload a large file to a node js instance using express and it will fail with large files.
With the following errormessage:

```
Error: Request aborted
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:107:19)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at abortIncoming (http.js:1892:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1904:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
/server/upload/

buffer.js:194
  this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
                ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:194:21)
    at fs.js:220:16
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
31 Jul 14:01:04 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What can I do to prevent this error when I don't want to chunk the data?

Hope someone can help to solve ;-)

Comment: Did you try increasing max upload file size? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574368/dynamically-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-node-js

Comment: @mak Yes I did (before express.bodyParser()) and there's no change...

Comment: I doubt Express was written with 1GB file uploads in mind. I would start looking into streaming the data. http://maxogden.com/node-streams

Comment: You can edit your answer to add what you've already tried (and include code).

Comment: @mak ok think I will strem the data now thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: I had similar issues with Amazon S3 and the key is to do it as a background job. Check this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue, Oh sorry saw you were uploading to Node.js, then ignore Kue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you analyse the error message

```
buffer.js:194
   this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
            ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
```

You can see that kMaxLength is a constant that specify the memory limit of a process.
From https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ

> Currently, by default v8 has a memory limit of 512mb on 32-bit
>   systems, and 1gb on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting
>   --max-old-space-size to a maximum of ~1gb (32-bit) and ~1.7gb (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your single process
>   into several workers if you are hitting memory limits.

So you can execute node with the flag

```
node --max-old-space-size=2000 app.js
```

The flag units is in MB see ( https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/ChangeLog)