# How to read large json file in node js?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a JSON file about 300MB in size and I'm trying to read it but it's not working.

How can I read a large JSON file? If anyone can guide me with a small piece of code then it would be great.

I have already tried **`fs.readFile`** but no luck, it's working fine for smaller files but not for large ones.

Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
app.get('/getData', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./uploads/test.json', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err
      var jsonData = data;
      var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
      res.json(jsonParsed);
    });
});
```

Comment: What "does not work"?  Do you get an error?  Run out of memory?  Take too long?  What exactly is the problem?  For starters, `if (err) throw err` should log.  And, you can put a `try/catch` with logging in the `catch` around `JSON.parse()`.  You should at least start by logging possible errors in this code. This takes ***some elemental debugging*** on your part before any of us could help you.  You should do that before you come here and then tell us what you found.

Comment: It's possible that 300MB of JSON is too large for your environment.  There are stream parsers for JSON that might be more memory efficient.  At 300MB, I'd personally be looking at a database, not a JSON file for storage.

Comment: Have you looked at something like this? https://itnext.io/using-node-js-to-read-really-really-large-files-pt-1-d2057fe76b33

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a large file (1GB) with node and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969880/upload-a-large-file-1gb-with-node-and-express)

Comment: FYI, CSV is simpler to read serially line by line if that's appropriate for what you're storing.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for not being clear with my question, actually as per your suggestion i first uploaded the file to a database (in mongo) using gridfs but when i'm retrieving it , it's taking too much time, almost 5 minutes. how can i make it process faster ?

Answer (score 3):

Speculating from the code snippet, I believe there is no requirement to do any modification (i.e. filtering) to the JSON data prior dispatching the response. If that is the case, parsing of the JSON would be unnecessary and Node.js's built-in [readable streams](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) could be used to provide more efficiency.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'citylots.json')).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: Is `res` a WritableStream? I would have just used `res.sendFile(jsonFile)`

Comment: @slebetman Yes, the `res` object is an [`enhanced`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) version of Node’s [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) class which inherits [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream).

Comment: @slebetman The `sendFile` method implemented via [`send`](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) utilises the exact [same](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/master/index.js#L798) technique above but since the content type is know beforehand the above saves few function calls. Regardless, the `sendFile` is a commodious alternate too!

Comment: @AshenGunaratne with your solution i'm getting the data but it's taking too much time to load , is there any way to make it process faster ?

Comment: @rajatmeena - What are you expecting?  It takes awhile to stream 300MB to the client.  Fix your design so you don't need to send 300MB to the client.  Keep the data on the server and let the client make ajax requests to fetch what it needs.  Or, send the data in small chunks and let the client request only what it needs when it needs it.